# Android Send password in email (hidden body?)

Tags: android, email

In my app the user can have a password for certain stuff. In case they forget it I want to add the option to send the password to their e-mail address (a dialog pops up with an edittext, users give in they email address, password is sent).
So either the body should be hidden or the mail should be sent without the user choosing a mail client.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you'd want your client to send the email, which is not how it is done. Instead the client inputs the emailadress which gets sent to your server, which in turn runs a script that will a] check for a valid email in your database (b] change the password to some temporary password) c] emails (this temporary) password to the valid email address

The way you describe, anyone could enter any email address and get the password ;)

Comment: This didn't occur to me :) However, I don't think in case of this app anyone would "steal" the password but family members